# Erroneous input value to Reducer in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have defined a custom writable (called *EquivalenceClsAggValue*) which has a field of type ArrayList (called *aggValues*) in Hadoop. Using my test data, the size of *aggValues* for each output entry by the Mapper in 2. However, when I check the size of *aggValues* in the Reducer, it gives me different size! That is, the size accumulates (first element has has 2, second one has size 4, third has size 6, and so on). What can be the problem?

This is how I output in the Mapper:

```
EquivalenceClsAggValue outputValue = new EquivalenceClsAggValue();
                .....

output.collect(new IntWritable(outputValue.aggValues.size()),outputValue);
```

And in the Reducer:

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<EquivalenceClsAggValue> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
     while(values.hasNext()){
            EquivalenceClsAggValue e = values.next();
            output.collect(new Text(key.toString()), new IntWritable(e.aggValues.size()));
.....
```

and the output is:

2   2

2   4

2   6

Comment: Can you post the EquivalenceClsAggValue class? Or at least relevant parts of it, such as readFields/writeFields, and other methods that deal with aggValues?

Answer (score 0):

In your `readFields` method, you need to clear out any previous contents of the array list - Hadoop re-uses the same object between calls.

Sorry, i missed this in [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249128/implementation-of-custom-writable-in-hadoop):

```
@Override
public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
  // add this statement to clear out previous contents
  aggValues.clear();

  int size = arg0.readInt();

  for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
    SortedMapWritable tmp = new SortedMapWritable();
    tmp.readFields(arg0);
    aggValues.add(tmp);
  }       
}
```