# Hadoop Deserialisation not working for List

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following custom object created as part of my Map Reduce Program:

```
public class Sales implements Writable{

    private List<Double> growthValues;

    public List<Double> getGrowthValues() {
        return growthValues;
    }

    public void setGrowthValues(List<Double> growthValues) {
        this.growthValues = growthValues;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        int size=in.readInt();
        Double dValue;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            dValue=in.readDouble();
            growthValues.add(dValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(growthValues.size());
        for(Double d:growthValues){
             out.writeDouble(d);            
        }

    }

}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException at the following line:
growthValues.add(dValue);
which means that dValue is null.

Is it because i have List and it should be a type which implements Writable interface?

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: pls have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249128/implementation-of-custom-writable-in-hadoop

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting a NullPointerException at the following line:
>   growthValues.add(dValue); which means that dValue is null.

This is wrong. It means `growthValues` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the step to create the actual list on deserialization.

```
    int size = in.readInt();
    growthValues = new ArrayList<>(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        growthValues.add(in.readDouble());
    }
```